# Reduce opacity all pixels in a html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'd like to know how can I reduce the alpha of all pixels in a html canvas.

I draw free lines on the canvas through a mouse input, so trying to redo some pre-programmed shapes it's not a solution for me.

The goal is to add a fadeOut effect on the image, so I was trying to do it with this function:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img  = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var alpha = 1.0;

while(alpha > 0){
  context.save();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.globalAlpha = alpha;
  context.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
  context.restore();

  alpha = alpha - .01;
  console.log(alpha);
  img  = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: Why not reduce the opacity of the full canvas with CSS?

Comment: nothing happens, @lemieuxster : (. But reducing the globalAlpha reduces the opacity only for new drawings.

Comment: Haven't thought on that, @R.Schifini. I'll see what happens.

Comment: @R.Schifini reducing the opacity of the div that contains the canvas worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reducing the opacity of the container div will easily reduce the contained canvas's opacity.

If you don't want the whole canvas to fade, it might be useful to combine an increasing transparency with `globalAlpha` with `copy` compositing. The `copy` compositing will let you redraw your existing custom drawings without using the very expensive `putImageData`.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var alpha=1.00;
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300";
function start(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}

function fade(decrement){
  alpha-=decrement
  if(alpha<0.01){ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);return}
  ctx.globalAlpha=alpha;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='copy';
  ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,img.width,img.height);
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
}

$('#go').click(function(){
  fade(0.10);
});

$('#fadeit').click(function(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animateFadeOut);
});

function animateFadeOut(){
  fade(0.01);
  if(alpha>0.00){requestAnimationFrame(animateFadeOut);}
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=go>Repeatedly click to fade out the image</button>
<br>
<button id=fadeit>Animate a fadeout</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Looks nice, but can you please just improve the answer by getting the content of the canvas instead of drawing a presetted image? As I said, I have some free drawings on the canvas, so I need to know how get its content to redraw it with the fade effect.

Comment: Check my updated code which *uses the existing canvas as the image source instead of a preset image*. :-) To explain: `drawImage(canvas,0,0,iw,ih,0,0,iw,ih)` will grab the existing canvas drawings (including your user's free-form drawings) and will paste them back onto the same canvas. Since `globalAlpha` is reduced, the redrawn free-form drawings will be more and more transparent. BTW, I haven't tried to recreate your drawing program just for the answer demo, but your actual drawing app will work the same as the demo's "world" image. Cheers!

Comment: The edit code didn't showed to me here, but I fixed it and it worked here!

Comment: sorry! Maybe it was a misclick... I swear I didn't downvoted on purpose

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @markE thanks for the snippet, it will help me out with a PoC :)